# If and only if condition on $B$ when $\mathrm{tr}(AB)-\mathrm{tr}(A)\geq0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

For $a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R}^+$ for all $i=1,\cdots,n$,  I want to find if and only if condition on $b_i$'s when 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i\geq\sum_{i=1}^na_i.
\end{equation}

To transform this problem to linear algebra problem let $A=\mathrm{diag}\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$ and $B=\mathrm{diag}\{b_1,\cdots,b_n\}$. Then I have to find a condition on $B$, such that 
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{tr}(AB)-\mathrm{tr}(A)\geq0.
\end{equation}
Is there any linear algebra theorem related to the last inequality?
Is this problem formulated correctly or additional information is needed?

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to find some $b_i$'s such that *for every* $n$-tuple of $a_i$'s the inequality holds? In this case, this happens iff $b_i\geq 1$ for every $i$.

Comment: that what first came to my mind. However, lets assume $a_1\geq\cdots\geq a_n$, then maybe some combination of $b_i$'s (not necessarily $\geq1$) guarantees that  the inequality holds

Comment: So you really want a necessary and sufficient condition on all pairs of sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$? I don't think you're going to find anything simpler than the inequality as written.

Comment: yes, for any given $A$, I wanted to find iff condition on $B$. I guess my question is not formulated correctly. Thanks guys

Comment: @Lee I honestly don't think you can really formulated much better. Even if $A$ is fixed, and you let $B$ vary, this doesn't simplify anything; the condition will still need to characterise when a pair $(A, B)$ satisfies the inequality (if you had given a specific $A$, e.g. $\operatorname{diag}(1, 2, 3, \ldots, n)$, that would be another story!). All we can do is manipulate the inequality, and there's no equivalent form that comes out much simpler. It's like you're asking us to characterise real numbers $x, y$ such that $x + y \ge 10$... what can you say that's simpler than that?